# Need to output each item from a list in a for cycle (python)

Tags: django, list, loops

I have a list

```
{{category_masks}}
```

And i have a code

```
 {% for pansion in pansions %}
    <div class="card">
        <a href="{{ pansion.get_absolute_url }}">
            <img src="{{ pansion.preview_picture.url }}" alt="{{ pansion.title}}" class="preview-picture">
        </a>
        <div class="pe-3 ps-3 d-flex flex-column h-100">
            <p class="name mb-3">
                <a href="{{ pansion.get_absolute_url }}">
                    {% if pansion.title_mask and category_masks %}
                        {{category_masks.0}} {{pansion.title_mask}}
                    {% else %}
                        {{ pansion.title }}
                    {% endif %}
                </a>
            </p>    
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

I need to output each item from {{category_masks}} to the pansion element in turn. If the list of {{category_masks}} ends, then the loop is repeated

*{{category_masks.0}} just output first element in all pansions, it's a test for me now, it's doesn't matter for now*

Note. I don't need to output all {{category_masks}} in one pansion element

Anyone have an ideas?

Increments are not work in jinja, i am already tried

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution :)

We will need to create a filter in views.py

```
@register.filter
def cycle_list(mylist, index):
    return mylist[index % len(mylist)]
```

And you html page

```
{% for pansion in pansions %}
    <div class="card">
        <div>   
                <a href="{{ pansion.get_absolute_url }}">
                    {% if pansion.title_mask and category_masks %}
                        {{ category_masks|cycle_list:forloop.counter0 }} {{ pansion.title_mask }}
                    {% else %}
                        {{ pansion.title }}
                    {% endif %}
                </a>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```